# Ejecutar una acción y actualizar la página, javascript

Tags: javascript

Al momento de ejecutar una función por medio de javascript indico la instrucción de generar un nuevo .pdf en otra pestaña y de igual manera actualizar la página en la cual estoy trabajando, pero sólo me actualiza la página y no genera el pdf. 
¿Me podrían decir qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
function AceptarTransferencia()
{
    if (document.frmDatos.txtIdTransfer.value=="")
    {
        alert("No ha seleccionado la solicitud de transferencia, que desea aprobar.");
    }
    else
    {       
        var x = window.confirm("Esta seguro que desea aprobar la solicitud de transferencia:"+document.frmDatos.txtIdTransfer.value)
        if (x==true)
        {
            alert('A continuacion se imprimira su "Ficha de Control de la Transferencia" realizada.');
            var indice=document.getElementById("OpcionAnio").selectedIndex;
            var aniosel=document.frmDatos.listaAnios.value;             
            //para que abra una nueva ventana para el reporte               
            document.frmDatos.target="_blank";                              
            //Para que pase los valores                             
            document.frmDatos.action="reportes/FichaControlAC.php?Usuario=<?php echo $Usuario; ?>";
            //para que abra el reporte
            document.frmDatos.submit(); 

            //para que al seguir trabajando con esta pagina no empieze a abrir ventanas             
            document.frmDatos.target="_parent";

            document.getElementById("OpcionAnio").selectedIndex=indice;                             
            alert("La pagina sera actualizada.");
            document.frmDatos.action='frmAutorizaTransf.php?AnioSeleccionado='+aniosel;
            //Para que me lleve los valores al otro formulario
            document.frmDatos.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as intentado probar solo el pdf, para ver si te esta funcionando?

Comment: Ya, si ejecuto el pdf sí hace la función y correctamente, pero cuando meto la actualización ya no hace el pdf.